# How to reset a VS Code terminal broken by vi?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use a VS code terminal on Windows 10, running a bash shell in WSL emulation.
If I run a "vi foo" in that terminal, it works but at exit the terminal rows are "broken". Issuing lots of "ls" commands doesn't scroll continuously.

I tried the historical "reset" shell command (used to work in VT-220 terms en 80', works in xterm, etc).
I tried the "Terminal clear" from the Commands Palette.

The same defect appears in the "Windows Terminal (Preview)" (Version: 0.10.761.0).
I run a Ubuntu distro in WSL.

Comment: I encounter some weird problems with vscode terminal too. Doing a system('clear') call mangles it too. Not sure how to fix besides restarting x.